# How can I replace NaN values with other values in the CustomerID column if they have a same InvoiceNo?

Tags: python, pandas

| InvoiceNo | StockCode | Quantity | InvoiceDate | UnitPrice | CustomerID | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 573415 | 23434 | 20 | 2011-10-30 16:17:00 | 0.79 | 13607.0 | UK |
| :-------- | :--------- | :--------- | :------------------- | :--------- | :---------- | :------- |
| 539050 | 22480 | 2 | 2010-12-15 16:21:00 | 1.25 | 12577.0 | France |
| :-------- | :--------- | :--------- | :------------------- | :--------- | :---------- | :------- |
| 573415 | 23434 | 1 | 2011-01-13 14:29:00 | 4.13 | NaN | UK |
| :-------- | :--------- | :--------- | :------------------- | :--------- | :---------- | :------- |
| 573151 | 84692 | 25 | 2011-10-27 20:09:00 | 0.42 | 17602.0 | UK |
| :-------- | :--------- | :--------- | :------------------- | :--------- | :---------- | :------- |
| 539050 | 22480 | 4 | 2011-12-02 16:39:00 | 10.79 | NaN | UK |
| :-------- | :--------- | :--------- | :------------------- | :--------- | :---------- | :------- |

Here I would like to replace the `NaN` values in the `CustomerID` with the values in `CustomerID` column if the `InvoiceNo` values are same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each invoice id has only 1 unique customer id something like this should work:

```
df["CustomerID"] = df.groupby("InvoiceNo")["Customer ID"].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

The code above simply makes groups based on the customer id and forward an backward fills all NA values.